# Is there a way to change the order of arguments in functions like paste, which take vectors in an order, to make it compatible with piping operators?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a long series of code using pipes, which end in the argument to be submitted to paste(). Smth like this

```
"string1" %>% paste ("string2", sep = "_")
```

results in "string1_string2". However I would like "string2_string1". Is there a solution apart from saving the variabes and running a new command? Is there a solution within stringr package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.` as placeholder for piped value.

```
"string1" %>% paste("string2", ., sep = "_")
#[1] "string2_string1"
```

Same would work with `stringr::str_c` -

```
"string1" %>% stringr::str_c("string2", ., sep = "_")
#[1] "string2_string1"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R` (`R 4.1.0`)

```
"string1" |>
    {\(x) paste("string2", x, sep = "_")}()
[1] "string2_string1"
```